# How to access Bootstrap Files individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Now that Bootstrap is running in Rails, I want to have full access to all Bootstrap-files, to exclude (or include) assets as I wish, and additionally add my own assets, variables - which I did (and found easy) before I started to learn Rails.

My question: Would it be a good practise to copy the whole bootstrap folder from `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bootstrap-sass-2.1.1.0\vendor\assets\stylesheets` to my Rails application folder e.g. `..\Rails\Sample_App\vendor\assets\stylesheets` which is there by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you mean "full access"? When you use `bootstrap-sass` gem, you already have all stylesheet and javascript of bootstrap. To use them, you just need add:

- `@import "bootstrap"` in your `custom.css.scss` file.
- `//= require bootstrap` in your `application.js` file.

So if you want to add your own assets, just put them into `app/assets/stylesheet`, create your own variables in your `custom.css.scss` or whatever your scss file and you can use them.

You can use all less variable of bootstrap, but you need small change. Bootstrap is using less, variable is defined: `@varibale`, with `bootstrap-sass` gem, you can use less variable of bootstrap in scss file, just change `@` to `$`, means `$variable`.

If you don't want to use stylesheet are scss files and you want to put individually assets:

- `app/assets` is place where you put all assets only is used by application
- `lib/assets` is place where you assets are shared by many applications.
- `vendor/assets` is place where you put copied assets of other developers, or plugins...

Comment: "Full access" means i have them in my project, and can import assets at hand - which possibly with `@import 'bootstrap/theasset'` - but sometimes I want to alter the files. I like the "magic" of files being imported with one line, but on the other hand be free to mess with them without distroying the origin.

Comment: so, you will need download them and put it in places by hand as my answer, and you're also not need to use `bootstrap-sass` gem anymore.

Comment: AAH, ok! Only to be sure - I can put the framework in `app/assets/stylesheets` if i want - and then I don´t need the gem. That´s what I was looking for!

Comment: yes, the gem only help you use bootstrap without doing by hand, and it use `sass` syntax instead of `less` syntax of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go by just adding the gem in the Gemfile and include the files by hand.

```
#application.css.less
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

For a really nice screencast on how to do this you can watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap where this technique is explained

Comment: But IF (sometimes it´s just nice to look into the files how things are done..) where would be the best place to put it? `app/assets/...`, `lib/assets/...` or the `vendor/assets/...` folder?

Comment: use gem edit. gem install gem-edit; gem edit bootstrap-sass. or bundle open bootstrap-sass in your project tree

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want them in production, which would override the gem's installed files, but rather just want to see the files for reference, then you should simply clone the git repository in a different directory than your project. So **in some other directory**, execute this:

```
git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

Of course, you can always browse the source conveniently online at [Github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap)