# Bootstrap has different behavior in plain html and rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I created a web page using the bootstrap grid.
This page is rendered perfectly, as expected, when I just open it with a browser.
The container in bootstrap is smaller than the screen, everything is perfect.

BUT, if I render the exact same page as an application.html.erb layout in rails, it always send this message to the browser: @media (min-width: 1200px). This makes my page become a bit bigger than my screen. The rest is fine. Bootstrap works but the container width is too big! In the plain page it is 960px, which is perfect!

Why?

I don't want this to happen! It is really weird. I read some posts where people say it happened to them, but I have the two pages side by side and "inspect element" shows @media (min-width: 1200px) in the css of the "row" class in the rails page and nothing in the other!

I am totally not willing to hack the bootstrap css. I would just like to figure out what is happening and fix it ! I would really like to use it as a stylesheet and not as a gem...

thanks so much in advance!

P.S.:
*In rails, I copied the bootstrap folder in my /assets/stylesheets/ directory*

Comment: You're going to need to show us the plain html page, the rails layout file (and maybe the rendered source HTML for both?), and the stylesheets manifest.  Without seeing that we're not going to be able to help...

Comment: will do really soon! Thanks about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding your own style in the file 'bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less' (or any other you have)?
In my own CSS, I have this:

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
}
```

and the problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answers to my questions regarding Bootstrap & Rails provide you with some insight:

[How to access Bootstrap Files individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379746/how-to-access-bootstrap-files-individually)

[How to pass Bootstrap-Variables in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396380/how-to-pass-bootstrap-variables-in-rails)

Comment: these are very useful posts Rockbot!